# Monitor Directory for Changes

Tags: linux, unix, file-io, listeners

Much like a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112276/directory-modification-monitoring), I am trying to monitor a directory on a Linux box for the addition of new files and would like to immediately process these new files when they arrive. Any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

With inotify you can watch a directory for file creation.

Comment: Inotify does not support recursively watching directories, meaning that a separate inotify watch must be created for every subdirectory. Keep this in mind.

Comment: Also see package called [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why) and its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab). I'm not sure how it handles sub-folders.

Comment: No, incron does not handle sub-folders, it totally failed on an appropriate "indiegogo" campaign, and incron dozed off in 2012. Sad, but it reached a blind-alley. I really hope, inotify will stay ;-)

Answer (score 25):

First make sure **`inotify-tools`** in installed.

Then use them like this:

```
logOfChanges="/tmp/changes.log.csv" # Set your file name here.

# Lock and load
inotifywait -mrcq $DIR > "$logOfChanges" &
IN_PID=$$

# Do your stuff here
...

# Kill and analyze
kill $IN_PID
while read entry; do
   # Split your CSV, but beware that file names may contain spaces too.
   # Just look up how to parse CSV with bash. :)
   path=... 
   event=...
   ...  # Other stuff like time stamps?
   # Depending on the event…
   case "$event" in
     SOME_EVENT) myHandlingCode path ;;
     ...
     *) myDefaultHandlingCode path ;;
done < "$logOfChanges"
```

Alternatively, using `--format` instead of `-c` on `inotifywait` would be an idea.

Just `man inotifywait` and `man inotifywatch` for more infos.

You can also use **`incron`** and use it to call a handling script.

Comment: Thanks, best answer so far. I was sure there was something nifty with inotify and this is exactly it.Works like a charm.

Comment: ADDENDUM: If you want to avoid thrashing your SSD, put the file in a `tmpfs` mount. My entire `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` for that very reason. Also helps with the clean up, because a reboot suffices to empty it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I thought of is to create a "file listener" coupled with a cron job.  I'm not crazy about this but I think it could work.

Comment: If you want to process them ASAP, there is no way around inotify.

Answer (score 0):

[fschange (Linux File System Change Notification)](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/index.html)  is a perfect solution, but it needs to patch your kernel

Comment: Note the warning at the top of the article, 
```fschange is an alternative to inotify that [was] implemented before inotify became part of the mainline Linux kernel. ```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [entr](https://eradman.com/entrproject/) or man entr.

With entr, you can watch a directory for file creation or modification easier than inotify.