# PHP script listening on a directory

Tags: php, linux, automation

I have a PHP script configured to loop endlessly using `set_time_limit(0)` and `for(;;)`. The script is coded to listen on a specific directory and wait for files. When files are detected, execute some commands and keep the loop going. So far this has been very successful for my needs, but I have concerns.

Are there any performance disadvantages to creating an infinite loop in PHP? 
How can I configure my server so that this script never stops running? Or perhaps alerts me when it has stopped running? I'd like it to launch on startup too. I have a SUSE SLES 10 box.

```
for (;;) {
    // Check for empty directory
    if (isEmptyDir($finishedDir)) {         
        // If so, move on
        continue;
    } else {
       // do stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem with runnin infinite loops. Just remember to sleep once in a while, or else the script will eat CPU cycles up for breakfast.

Comment: It's possible that you could use a `cron`.

Comment: Alright then. I am using sleep() in the 'do stuff' part, but that only occurs when a file is actually detected. Should I be using sleep() at the end of every loop, regardless if a file is found or not?

Answer (score 1):

This may work, but PHP is not really designed for these kinds of daemon-like jobs. Linux/Unix has tailor-made tools like `inotify` that are guaranteed to perform better, and that can trigger a PHP script when a change event happens.

See this SO question: [Monitor Directory for Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511463/monitor-directory-for-changes)

Comment: ++ PHP has an Inotify extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using memory (eg: memcached, apc) instead of using file because accessing a file is more costly than accessing the memory. And consider using a little `sleep()`s in order to add time interval.