# How do I create a monitor for a specific directory?

Tags: java, windows, directory, monitor

Using Java over Windows Vista, I'm trying to create a kind of a monitor for a directory, so every time this directory is modified (new, renamed, updated or deleted files) a process is triggered. I tried to do this with a loop that will execute a `dir` in the directory and analyze all the files. But this is very time and memory consuming, specially when the number of files start to grow. I think there should be a better way to do that.

**note**: there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112276/directory-modification-monitoring) in SO for this, but it's for C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't wait for Java 7 and the [WatchService](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6) you'll have to do something like this:

```
final File watched = new File("[path of directory to watch]");
long lastModified = watched.lastModified();
while(true) {
    if (watched.lastModified() > lastModified) {
        // Change happened in the directory do what you want.
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000); // 2 second interval
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks better than the one I'm using currently. I'll try it while Java 7 is not with me.

Comment: You'll have to handle some possible exceptions being thrown in my code. `Thread.sleep()` and the IO operation can throw exceptions.

Comment: I like TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2) myself

Comment: you should set lastMofidied = watched.lastModified also inside the if Statement otherwise the statement is always true after the first change

Comment: @MartinDürrmeier Agreed, this is a bug, people should be careful with this code.

Answer (score 4):

> I think there should be a better way
>   to do that.

You're right, there should be a better way and its coming with Java 7. See the upcoming [WatchService API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/).

Without getting an RC build, I don't know if there is a portable way to do what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you monitoring ? I would expect that you should simply have to monitor the modification time of the directory, and then check the modification times of the files if the directory has been modified.

So I would expect to store a `Map` of filenames vs. modification times (for the checking at least).

Unfortunately there isn't an *easy* means to use Java to check a directory for changes other than polling the directory in some capacity. See [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096404/is-there-a-sophisticated-file-system-monitor-for-java-which-is-freeware-or-open-s/1096876#1096876) wrt. this question and libraries you can use to simplify this (plus the Java 7 feature)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use JNI to call ReadDirectoryChangesW. You could use FirstFirstChangeNotification and FindNextChangeNotification instead, but unless you need compatibility with old (16-bit) versions of Windows, I'd advise against it.